# Java JFrame Item Positions/Sizes

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am aware of the methods and coding required to set a JFrame item's position and size, but I need a bit of help knowing how to correctly size and position items. Is there a way to use another JFrame API/method to separate the window into sections to make positioning items easier? What are the maximum values for height and width? How do I set a button to an average size? If you have some experience with JFrames, please give me some info about this to help me understand how to position and size JFrame items.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

Comment: Already seen it, it doesn't help much because it is an explanation of what I already know, I just need some basic information about maximum heights, widths, and normal button sizes.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be worrying about pixel perfect positioning of components. Swing wasn't meant to be used as such. Being a language that is meant to be run on many different platforms, the GUI library should be flexible as such. To maintain the flexibility, layout managers are introduced. You should be using these layout managers do the sizing and positioning *for* you.

You can see a visualization of how each work at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). With these layout managers, you'll want to learn (at the very least)

- Which ones respect preferred size and which ones don't.
- how each ones are represented visually.
- How to create white space, using gaps, empty borders, struts
- How use use nested containers with different layout managers to get your desired result.

It may intimidating with all the different possibilities, but like learning anything new, take it one step at a time. Go through each tutorial for each layout manager.

Comment: That helped, I chose the FlowLayout for the layout manager and it seems to be working well, but there is a problem. I can't seem to add more than 3 rows with FlowLayout. I use a new pane for each row, and I've even tried using nested panes but it always sorts them into 3 rows and sometimes places rows on top of each other or makes a really long row with the content of the last two. Is it possible to have more than 3 rows with FlowLayout?

Comment: Edit your post with the code, and explain how you want it to look, and I'll vote reopen the question and have a look at it. Make sure you'll let me know when you've done it, so I can do that.

Comment: I posted a new question with code and more info, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981835/more-than-3-rows-with-flowlayout